# Using STL priority_queue with greater_equal comparator class

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

Running the following example I receive a debug assertion in the marked line.

```
std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater_equal<int>> queue_int;
queue_int.push(1);
queue_int.push(2);
queue_int.push(1); // Debug Assertion Failed: Expression invalid comparator
```

Any hints? Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the time when you are using a STL data structure with a comparator, that comparator needs to be strict and never return true if it is receiving equal object to compare.

Imagine the case when 2 equal objects are compared, swapped and the next comparation will be again between the same 2 objects. In this case the STL sort step will never stop.

Try `std::greater` instead of `std::greater_equal`

Comment: I understood your explanation but I'm still wondering about std::greater_equal? Could you come up with an example on when to use it...

Comment: I don't think that std::greater_equal is ever used for STL data structures (but maybe I am wrong). Almost all the time you will find in STL more functions than you strictly need, because somebody could use them in personal tasks. Tasks like: count the elements in an array >= 0 (find the example here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/greater_equal/ )

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour. Your implementation is nice, and asserts when it detects that. The comparator used with `std::priority_queue` must meet the named requirement [*Compare*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare). `std::greater_equal` does not, because it returns true if you pass it equal values.

From the relevant documentation

> The type `T` satisfies *Compare* if
>
> Given
>
> - `comp`, an object of type `T`
>
> Requirements
>
> - For all `a`, `comp(a,a)==false`

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -2):

Can not reproduce with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::priority_queue<int, std::vector<int>, std::greater_equal<int>> queue_int;
    queue_int.push(1);
    queue_int.push(2);
    queue_int.push(1); // Debug Assertion Failed: Expression invalid comparator
    return 0;
}
```

And compilation line:

```
$ g++ -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp
```

Please specify exact compilation flags used